Autocomplete not showing suggestions
I'm trying to make primeng autocomplete component work using formly (json) but I'm stuck as suggestions are not displayed: onComplete function is clearly working as results are back from the ws call. I'm sure I'm missing something probably linked to the overlay panel?
Here is a stackblitz: first panel is straight using primeng component, second one is trying to use formly (type PARIS for example or any other french city).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xk42bm?file=src%2Fformly-types%2Fautocomplete-type.ts
Thanks in advance for your help.

You are assigning f.props['results'] = this.suggestionsCodePostalCommune before the searchCodePostalCommune method is triggered. This will not automatically update the search result to f.props['results'].
You should update for each time the search result is returned as below:
searchCodePostalCommune(event: AutoCompleteCompleteEvent) {
  this.adresseService
    .searchCodePostalCommune(event.query)
    .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef))
    .subscribe((s) => {
      let codepostalOuCommune = this.fields[0].fieldGroup!.find((x) =>
        x.key?.toString().includes('codepostalOuCommune')
      );
      if (codepostalOuCommune && codepostalOuCommune?.props)
        codepostalOuCommune.props['results'] = s.features;

      this.suggestionsCodePostalCommune = s.features;
    });
}

Besides, this solves the option drop-down list not showing. You have another issue that the displayed option is blank due to the field="label", there is no label field/property in the objects from props.results.
If you want to achieve the same displayed options as your first panel with PrimeNG, you can pass the template:

Define the featureItemTemplate for the displayed option template.

<ng-template #featureItemTemplate let-feature>
  <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2 font-semibold">
    {{ feature.properties.postcode }} -
    {{ feature.properties.label }}
  </div>
  <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2 text-xs">
    {{ feature.properties.context }}
  </div>
</ng-template>


Modify AutocompleteProps to allow passing the itemTemplate value.

interface AutocompleteProps extends FormlyFieldProps {
  results: unknown[];
  searchObject(event: { query: string }): void;
  itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}


Get featureItemTemplate from the view in the component with @ViewChild. You need to migrate the mapFields caller to ngAfterViewInit as the template is only after to obtain during the AfterViewInit lifecycle.

import {
  Component,
  DestroyRef,
  inject,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('featureItemTemplate', { static: true })
  featureItemTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.fields = this.mapFields(this.formlyJson);
}


Assign featureItemTemplate to f.props['itemTemplate'].

mapFields(fields: FormlyFieldConfig[]) {
  return fields.map((f) => {
    if (f.key?.toString().includes('codepostalOuCommune')) {
      if (f.props) {
        f.props['searchObject'] = (event: AutoCompleteCompleteEvent) =>
          this.searchCodePostalCommune(event);
        f.props['results'] = this.suggestionsCodePostalCommune;
        f.props['itemTemplate'] = this.featureItemTemplate;
      }
    }

    if (f.fieldGroup && f.fieldGroup.length > 0) {
      this.mapFields(f.fieldGroup);
    }

    return f;
  });
}


Render passed props.itemTemplate in the pTemplate="item". Don't forget to import CommonModule or NgTemplateOutlet into the imports array.

@Component({
  selector: 'formly-field-primeng-autocomplete',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...,
    NgTemplateOutlet, // No need to import if imported CommonModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class FormlyFieldAutocomplete extends FieldType<
  FieldTypeConfig<AutocompleteProps>
> {}

<p-autoComplete
  field="label"    
  [formControl]="formControl"
  [formlyAttributes]="field"
  [forceSelection]="true"
  [suggestions]="props.results"
  [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
  [inputStyle]="{ width: '100%' }"
  (completeMethod)="props.searchObject($event)">
    <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-feature>

      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="props.itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: feature }">
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>

Demo @ StackBlitz

Thanks a lot for your quick and clear explanation!
